# render_cell method from cells gem throwing deprecation warnings in rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, deprecation-warning, rails-cells

I ran my rspec test suite and everytime the **render_cell** method, from the *cells gem*, is called, the folowing deprecation warning shows:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: `named_routes.helpers` is deprecated, please use `route_defined?(route_name)` to see if a named route was defined. (called from block (4 levels) in <top (required)> at ...
```

Is it something from the gem internals, from rspec-cells gem, or will I have to change something in my routes?

OBS:

- ruby (2.2.2)
- rails (4.2.1)
- cells (3.11.3)
- rspec-rails (3.2.1)
- rspec-cells (0.2.2)

Comment: Are you calling that in your `config/routes.rb` file? If not, maybe file an issue with the gem project.

Comment: Nope, there is nothing there on the routes.rb. I'll put this issue on the gem project then. Can I link it on github from here?

Comment: Its already reported... It will be solved in Cells 4, as stated by the author here: https://github.com/apotonick/rspec-cells/issues/68

Comment: If that's the answer, might want to post it as one. It'll help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue Was already reported... It's solved in Cells 4, as stated by the author [here](http://github.com/apotonick/rspec-cells/issues/68).

Cells 4 have some important changes in its structure, as the removal of ActionView as template engine. [take a look](https://github.com/apotonick/cells).